# R.java permission denied Error in Eclipce in using old Workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Before some days I am using my eclipse in to Windows XP. I also have one another OS (Windows 7) in to another Drive. Now I want to use the Eclipse for Android from Windows 7.
But, While I have open Eclipse it gives me the Error like the Some file is locked.
Well I have solve that error from here: [This link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/665454/#msg_665454)

But now, If i open My old created Workspace in this Windows7's Eclipse then the project loaded but i am not able to open any project of that workspace.

If i load the existing workspace then it gives me error like:

```
unable to open class file. . ./R.java permission denied.
```

And If i open it from another new Workspace then it gives me error like :

```
[2011-09-07 12:03:25 - SpellingQuiz] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.4' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

Now What should i have to do ?
How can this problem resolve ??
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16512

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this thing will help you to solve your problem. this is rear case which raise with android :: 
[**click here to solve this**](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16512)

Comment: Actualy it was the error for the Windows platform changed. I have open Eclipse with "Run as Administrator" and it solve my problems.